# Develop android Application using Html,Css and JavaScript

Tags: android

I would like to develop Android application using HTML, CSS and JavaScript with Android SDK. I dont want to use another tool like Titanium or PhoneGap.

Is it possible to make application using the HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Are Android web apps as good as native apps? Can the same functionality be achieved through web apps?

If it is good in comparison of native applications, can any one tell me the proper way to do this or provide me good tutorial?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The Short answer: Yes, you can develop apps using HTML / CSS / Javascript.  Take two WebView Tutorials and call me in the morning.

The Long Answer:
If you want to write apps for Android that use HTML / CSS / Javascript, you'll have to at least create a native WebView wrapper.  This is relatively easy to do -- unless you want to hook into native functions, such as the accelerometer, camera, or even the Toast Messages (the little messages that pop up when something happens).

Accessing the native hardware and software through a webview requires you to write a JavascriptAdapter (available in Android 2+), and define some custom Javascript methods in the JavascriptAdapter.  Those methods map to a java function, which DOES have access to the native OS facilities.

Frameworks such as Appcelerator and PhoneGap do exactly this, except they've already written the javascript functions for you, so it saves you from having to write those yourself.

In that sense, if you're going to write an app for Android using HTML / CSS / Javascript, it makes sense to use a framework.  Otherwise, you're doing that work yourself.

Comment: Great answer.but it raises the question : why not all apps is doing this. why learn java to do it if i can learn javascript /css html ?

Comment: Apr 2015 news: [Execute JavaScript in Android without WebView](http://lifeofcoding.com/2015/04/05/Execute-JavaScript-in-Android-without-WebView/)

Comment: dosecam, writing for Android is originally supposed to be Java, other ways can do but it's a hack (a frameworked workaround).

Answer (score 5):

you can make a web application and convert it in android app (apk) by using javascript, HTML5 and deploy in phonegap.

[Develop Android Apps with html5 and Javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20130901120619/http://nextopics.com/develop-android-apps-with-html5-and-javascript/)

Comment: ". I dont want to use another tool like titanium and phone gap ."

Comment: @WilliamTWild Why?

Answer (score 2):

These days the easiest way to create Android apps based on HTML is to use **DroidScript** which can be found on Google Play.

The same tool also allows you to build native (non-HTML) apps with pure JavaScript and it's far easier to use than PhoneGap/Cordova because it's aimed at novice coders.

It's based on WebView actually, but all the hard work of handling the JS->Java bridge, permissions, local storage, APK building etc have been done for you by the DroidScript developers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pure HTML project (with JS / CSS / Images) you can use the WebIntoApp.com in order to do that online. Also, this website will build (and sign) the APK for you (free / dedicated plans).

https://www.webintoapp.com

(I'm the author)

Answer (score -1):

If you know JavaScript, switch to java or kotlin You don't need css and html. I think Android view structure is easier and more enjoyable than css.