# Creating android app with HTML, CSS and Javascript for User interface and coding it with java is it possible?

Tags: android

Yeah. My doubt is simple i would like to code in java but i want the user interface to be good look with the help of css. Can we do it without xml ?

Comment: You can use a `WebView` and add your own html and css into the `WebView`. But why won't you use XML and styling?

Comment: @darwind Thanks for the reply but how can we style XML like we do to our html tags using css ? i dont think its possible. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You can't, but you can inflate a `WebView` from your code and then populate it with `CSS` and `HTML`. That was what I was getting at ;-)

Comment: You need to make a decision between a native Android application (using Java and XML) or a web-app (using HTML, CSS, and whatever web technologies strike your fancy). You do not need CSS to make your XML layouts look good, but you will need to learn how to style elements with XML in the Android framework.

Comment: @Tanis.7x "you will need to learn how to style elements with XML in the Android framework" -- I think this is precisely what he was hoping to avoid, that's why he asked. ;) 

I would be grateful for solution, too, since life is too short not to try and avoid learning every cumbersome UI definition language invented. Automatic translation from subsets of HTML+CSS should be possible, but perhaps a replaceable layout engine would be easier.

To the asker: until it becomes possible, just use Android Studio to generate UI code for you. Or, if you've found a better way, please let us know!

Comment: Oops, just found [an older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785875/develop-android-application-using-html-css-and-javascript?rq=1), answered nicely. Should this be marked a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible, but not exactly without difficulties. See "[Develop android Application using Html,Css and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785875/develop-android-application-using-html-css-and-javascript?rq=1)".