# Create android apps with HTML,CSS,JS and without SDK

Tags: android

Ok, it's clear by question heading that I want to create android apps with HTML,CSS and JS. I know them very well and I just don't want to use SDK it's bulky, hard to understand and not User friendly just like [other google products](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/why-dislike-google-services/).

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785875/develop-android-application-using-html-css-and-javascript)  and many more articles but they lack when someone asks:

Can I Do it without that SDK?

> So whilst you can easily code your entire project just using notepad,
>   compilation will need the Android SDK.

I just want to do it online or by installing a less bulky software that just packs my app in apk (like a zip). I know it's too much but if someone know how to do this exactly.

Comment: Use cordova : http://cordova.apache.org/ to achieve this

Comment: I just don't want to build without sdj, I want it to be packed as apk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to use some Java to give your Android app functionality. JavaScript might work, but it depends on what exactly you want to do.

You also need other SDK tools to create APK packages. You *could* build your own tools to do that, since APKs aren't black magic (fortunately), but it would be tedious, cumbersome and fragile.

It's a lot easier to use an SDK to me.

Comment: does cs mean company secretary?