# How to use javascript api in android app?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook-chat

I would like to implement receiving and sending Facebook messages in my Android application. Since the official [Chat API will be deprecated starting 30 april 2015](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat), I can't use it.

I stumbled upon [this unofficial Facebook Chat API](https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api), but it uses JavaScript. Is there any way to use this API in my Android project? 
Note that I do NOT want to create a chat client, I want to use it to receive messages and send quick replies through notifications only. So I'm thinking I can't [use a WebView and just create my app using HTML/CSS/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785875/develop-android-application-using-html-css-and-javascript)?

Is there any other way to use this?

Comment: Just to throw it out there, an API is usually a term that refers to a web call or web request of some sort, and not a specific code like the one you found for javascript. What you have found seems to be a javascript library that calls a facebook API.

Comment: I think it's more of a library which provides an unofficial facebook API, no?

Comment: I have no idea. I havent looked at it enough to determine what it does and whether it uses official or unofficial stuff. I was just trying to help you clarify what you have and what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok thanks, the first text in the description is: "The Official Facebook Chat API uses XMPP and is going to be deprecated as of April 30th 2015. This is a non-official API that doesn't use XMPP.". 

So I'm looking for a way to use this non-official API in my Android application.